# How to pass parameter for Exec from notify?

Tags: puppet, exec

I've the following Puppet manifest:

```
# PHP Configuration
class php {

  exec { "php5enmod $module":
    path => "/usr/sbin",
    command => "php5enmod $module",
  }

  file {'/etc/php5/conf.d/upload_limits.ini':
    ensure => present,
    owner => root, group => root, mode => 444,
    notify => [ Exec["php5enmod upload_limits"], Service["apache2"] ],
    content => "post_max_size = 16M \nupload_max_filesize = 16M \n",
  }
  file {'/etc/php5/conf.d/memory_limits.ini':
    ensure => present,
    owner => root, group => root, mode => 444,
    notify => [ Exec["php5enmod memory_limits"], Service["apache2"] ],
    content => "memory_limit = 256M \n",
  }
}
include php
```

How I can create `exec` to use in `notify` by passing the parameter dynamically? It's something that's possible, or there is another better way of doing it?

---

The current code gives me errors like:

> Error: Could not find dependent Exec[php5enmod upload_limits] for File[/etc/php5/conf.d/upload_limits.ini]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this is running the `exec` first gets declared.
At that point $module is not set, so the exec title is `php5enmod`.
You are not passing a variable here, this is just a name.

In such a case a [defined type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/definedtypes.html) makes more sense.
Like this:

```
define php5enmod() {
  exec { "php5enmod_${title}":
    path        => "/usr/sbin",
    command     => "php5enmod $title",
    refreshonly => true,
    notify      => Service["apache2"]
  }
}

class php {

  php5enmod{ 'upload_limits': }
  file {'/etc/php5/conf.d/upload_limits.ini':
    ensure  => present,
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0444',
    content => "post_max_size = 16M \nupload_max_filesize = 16M \n",
    notify  => Php5enmod["upload_limits"],
  }

  php5enmod{ 'memory_limits': }
  file {'/etc/php5/conf.d/memory_limits.ini':
    ensure  => present,
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0444',
    content => "memory_limit = 256M \n",
    notify  => Php5enmod["memory_limits"],
  }

}

include php
```

Normally the `define` shouldn't be there.
It should probably be `php::php5enmod()` and have it's own file.
This is just to show the general concept.

Comment: This mostly works for me on Puppet 4.10.9 except the line:
    notify  => Php5enmod["upload_limits"],
needs to be:
  notify  => Exec["php5enmod_upload_limits"],
and then it works correctly.  I wonder if the syntax above used to work on a previous version?  I also used manifests/php5enmod.pp and scoped the define as php::php5enmod both in the define and in the instantiation from the class.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse your thinking!  Use [`Subscribe`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html#notify-and-subscribe) to link your variably-named `Exec` (bad form, IMHO) to the `File`.  [`Subscribe and Notify`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html#notify-and-subscribe) are complimentary; they do the same thing, but in differing directions.

Try something like [this](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-refreshonly)?

```
  exec { "php5enmod $module":
    path => "/usr/sbin",
    command => "php5enmod $module",
    subscribe => [File["/etc/php5/conf.d/upload_limits.ini"], File["/etc/php5/conf.d/memory_limits.ini"],
  }

  file {'/etc/php5/conf.d/upload_limits.ini':
    ensure => present,
    owner => root, group => root, mode => 444,
    notify => Service["apache2"]
    content => "post_max_size = 16M \nupload_max_filesize = 16M \n",
  }
  file {'/etc/php5/conf.d/memory_limits.ini':
    ensure => present,
    owner => root, group => root, mode => 444,
    notify => Service["apache2"]
    content => "memory_limit = 256M \n",
  }
```

Completely untested, but I think that'll get you started at least...

Comment: This has a flaw: $module is not set when exec gets declared. Meaning that the command getting executed will always be incomplete. See my answer for details